# C# AES decryption returns junk data

Tags: c#, aes

I am encrypting plain text using aes.js and decrypting in c#

Encryption Code in JS

```
var aesKey = "87E67EF6-ECFB-4295-ACA3-B3F06BE489B1-87E67EF6-ECFB-4295-ACA3-B3F06BE489B1";
var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(JSON.stringify(emailParams), aesKey, {
                keySize: 256,
                padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
});
var encAesKey = aesKey;
var encData = new Object();
encData.pId = 1234;
encData.encAesKey = encAesKey;
encData.encAesData = encrypted.toString();
```

I am trying to decrypt the encrypted string in C#

```
byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
Rijndael alg = Rijndael.Create();
Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(key, new byte[] { 0x43, 0x72, 0x6e, 0x6d, 0x54, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x94, 0x16, 0x32, 0x44, 0x84, 0x7e, 0x18, 0x64, 0x76, 0x6e, 0x63, 0x64, 0x7a, 0x5f, 0x84, 0x7f, 0x9a });
alg.KeySize = 256;
alg.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
alg.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
alg.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, alg.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
cs.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
//cs.Close();
string st = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ms.ToArray());
return st;
```

If I uncomment the line `cs.Close();` it is throwing "Padding is invalid and cannot be removed" at this line.
If I comment the line `cs.Close();` it is decrypting to junk data.
[image]

What would be cause for this? Am I missing anything?
Can you please help me to solve this

Comment: These two codes do not fit together at all because different KDFs are used. The CryptoJS counterpart to `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` is [`PBKDF2`](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#pbkdf2). A KDF is used in combination with a randomly generated salt, which is sent to the recipient together with the ciphertext. The IV is either generated (together with the key) via the KDF or separately (in the latter case also randomly and is sent together with the salt/ciphertext).

Comment: What would be the solution for this? I need to decrypt the encrypted string. Encrypted using CryptoJS.AES.encrypt

Comment: The current CryptoJS code uses the OpenSSL KDF `EVP_BytesToKey`. If the CryptoJS code cannot be changed, you need a C# counterpart, e.g. [here](https://gist.github.com/caspencer/1339719) (not tested). If the CryptoJS code can be changed, PBKDF2 would be a better alternative instead (better because `EVP_BytesToKey` is not a standard and has been deemed relatively insecure). Alternatively, the key can be used directly instead of a passphrase. So it depends on the requirements.

Comment: By the way `encrypt.encrypt(aesKey)` is not defined. Please post the corresponding code.

Comment: encrypt.encrypt(aesKey) is not required in this part. updated the question

Comment: OK (as long as the unencrypted key is not sent along with the data).

Comment: Here, aesKey should be encrypted using RSA public key

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't answer the question of @Topaco regarding your requirements I changed my sample codes to show a cross-platform encryption with AES CBC 256 and PBKDF2 key derivation.

Please note that I was too lazy to adopt my code to your specific data so I leave it up to you to get the input data as you like.

**Security warning: both codes do not have any exception handling and the number of PBKDF2 iterations (1000) is low due to Javascript running in a browser.** As well the salt & iv handling and splitting of the data needs some improvements.

The Javascript code (for encryption) gives an output of (concatenated) salt, iv and encrypted data that gets split up on C# side (for decryption) to feed the PBKDF2 and AES decryption functions.

Here are the outputs of both programs - you can run a live example of both programs here (
JS: https://repl.it/@javacrypto/SoJsAesCbcPbkdf2EncryptOnly#index.js , C#: https://repl.it/@javacrypto/SoCAesCbcPbkdf2DecryptOnly).

Javascript:

```
SO AES CBC 256 PBKDF2 encryption only (JS)
transitmessage: 8c22a29d14f5e1e1582a795bfec8e4f8b91af5e6390c1b0b598b7d0d63cd2e6f1LSz9IT93Fe6OwWYZ7Dpj1LrSIwsV46ccs3oV3A2FoBCH6+8Jp+fSLprYqh1adIJ
```

C#:

```
SO AES CBC 256 PBKDF2 decryption only (C#)
plaintext: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

Javascript code:

```
var CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");

console.log('SO AES CBC 256 PBKDF2 encryption only (JS)');

var keySize = 256;
var saltSize = 128;
var ivSize = 128;
var iterations = 1000;

var message = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";

var aesKey = "87E67EF6-ECFB-4295-ACA3-B3F06BE489B1-87E67EF6-ECFB-4295-ACA3-B3F06BE489B1";

// pbkdf2
var salt = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(saltSize/8);
var key = CryptoJS.PBKDF2(aesKey, salt, {
    keySize: keySize/32,
    iterations: iterations
  });

// encrypt
var iv = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(ivSize/8);
var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(message, key, { 
    iv: iv, 
    padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7,
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC
  });
var transitmessage = salt.toString()+ iv.toString() + encrypted.toString();
console.log('transitmessage:', transitmessage);
```

C# code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

public class Program {

    public static void Main() {
        Console.WriteLine("SO AES CBC 256 PBKDF2 decryption only (C#)");

    const int ITERATIONS = 1000; // number of pbkdf2 iterations
    String aesData = "87E67EF6-ECFB-4295-ACA3-B3F06BE489B1-87E67EF6-ECFB-4295-ACA3-B3F06BE489B1";
    // data coming from javascript CryptoJS encryption
    string data = "8c22a29d14f5e1e1582a795bfec8e4f8b91af5e6390c1b0b598b7d0d63cd2e6f1LSz9IT93Fe6OwWYZ7Dpj1LrSIwsV46ccs3oV3A2FoBCH6+8Jp+fSLprYqh1adIJ";

    // splitting the datastring
    string saltHex = data.Substring(0, 32);
    string ivHex = data.Substring(32, 32);
    string cipherBase64 = data.Substring(64, (data.Length - 64));
    //Console.WriteLine("saltHex: " + saltHex);
    //Console.WriteLine("ivHex: " + ivHex);
    //Console.WriteLine("cipherBase64: " + cipherBase64);

    // pbkdf2
    Rfc2898DeriveBytes pbkdf2 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(aesData, 
    StringToByteArray(saltHex), ITERATIONS);
    byte[] key = pbkdf2.GetBytes(32);

    // decryption
    string decryptedtext;
    using(Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create()) {
            aesAlg.Key = key;
            byte[] IV = StringToByteArray(ivHex);
            byte[] cipherText = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherBase64);
            aesAlg.IV = IV;
            aesAlg.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);
            using(var msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipherText)) {
                using(var csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read)) {
                    using(var srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt)) {
                        decryptedtext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    Console.WriteLine("plaintext: " + decryptedtext);
    }

  static byte[] StringToByteArray(String hex) {
    int NumberChars = hex.Length;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[NumberChars / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < NumberChars; i += 2)
    bytes[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(i, 2), 16);
    return bytes;
  }
}
```